# The type com.mongodb.WriteConcern cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files. How do I fix this error?

Tags: java, mongodb, eclipse, servlets, cookies

I have included **mongodb-driver-3.0.2.jar** and **bson-4.1.0.jar** in my application build path in Eclipse. After writing a simple code of inserting some documents in mongoDB database and executing it, I get this error:

```
The type com.mongodb.WriteConcern cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

This is my code:

```
package abhishek;              //<--- The error shows in this line
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;




@WebServlet("/Mongo_details")
public class Mongo_details extends HttpServlet {
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        String name="";
        String email="";
        String age="";
        Cookie[] cookie=request.getCookies();
        for(Cookie c: cookie) {
            
            if(c.getName().equals("name"))
                name=c.getValue();
            else if(c.getName().equals("email"))
                email=c.getValue();
            else
                age=c.getValue();
            
        }
            
            // creates database
            MongoClient ml=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
            DB db=ml.getDB("Storage");
            
// creates table
            DBCollection c=db.getCollection("Details");
            
// insert documents
            BasicDBObject doc=new BasicDBObject();
            doc.put("Name", name);
            doc.put("Email", email);
            doc.put("Age", age);
            c.insert(doc);
    
            
    }

}
```

Please help me fix this.

**EDIT:** Ok I found a fix, I removed the **mongodb-driver-3.0.2.jar** from my build path and added **mongo-java-driver-2.10.1**. But now its showing a new error in console:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.DBObject
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
... 40 more
```

But I have that class in my `com.mongodb` package

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the MongoDB server version you are accessing from your code? Is it a standalone or a cluster?

Comment: MongoDB community server 4.4.1 (latest)

Comment: Then try to use the latest of the Java drivers; v4.1.1 is just released (at least v3.12).

Comment: Tried with that, I still get the same error.